# Does the EU Common Fisheries Policy cover British Overseas Territories?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, fishing

Looking at what makes up the [UK Exclusive_economic_zone (EEZ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_economic_zone#United_Kingdom) it totals 6,805,586 square km. But of these only 773,676 square km are around UK proper and 426 around Gibraltar. The vast majority are around British Overseas Territories, which are not part of EU territory. E.g. 1,449,532 square km of EEZ are around South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands.

Does the EU Common Fisheries Policy (e.g. fishing quotas) cover all those non-EU British Overseas Territories?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The British Overseas Territories are not part of the EU, and not subject to EU treaties.

The governments of the [Falkland Islands](http://www.fig.gov.fk/fisheries/) (or [South Georgia](https://www.gov.gs/fisheries/overview/) respectively) set their own quotas and fishery policies.  The EU is a major customer for Falkland Island Squid. A large proportion of the calamari eaten in Spain comes from the Falklands. But as the Falklands are not part of the Customs Union, [there are meetings to negotiate terms](https://en.mercopress.com/2018/10/12/falklands-government-and-fishing-industry-seek-support-in-galicia)

Gibraltar is exceptional in that it is part of the EU, and so is subject to the various treaties, such as the CFP.

Comment: I think the [Sovereign Base Areas of Akrotiri and Dhekelia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akrotiri_and_Dhekelia) are also British Overseas Territories that are part of the EU.

Comment: I found an EU document on CFP beyond European waters, but it's mostly about their participation in other regional organizations (RFMOs) http://www.europarl.europa.eu/RegData/etudes/IDAN/2015/571323/EPRS_IDA(2015)571323_EN.pdf There are some EU guidelines for member states fleets, but no quotas.

Comment: N.B., if you're curious it was in connection with this question: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/43912/does-the-uk-provide-50-of-eus-waters-and-does-this-imply-anything-about-fishi